# MongoDB $match inside $cond

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider the following:

```
db.stores.aggregate( 
    { $project: { 
        _id: 0, 
        in_radius: { 
            $cond: { 
                if: <geoWithinExpression>, 
                then: 1, 
                else: 0 
            }
        }
    }
})
```

geoWithinExpression is actually:

```
$match: {
  location: {
    $geoWithin: {
      $center: [[lat, lon], radius]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm doing that so I can use $group on the result set for counting the number of stores in that radius. (I'm using $project since I want to do more custom columns like this one and return them all in one time).

Is this even possible?

Comment: check here it may help you, similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840720/conditonal-unwind-in-mongodbs-aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I was able to return exactly what I needed by using the `distanceField` added by `$geoNear` in the `$group` stage's `$cond`, using the aggregation interface:

```
[
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: [<lon>,<lat>],
      distanceField: "distance",
      spherical: true,
      maxDistance: <extended_radius_distance_in_radians>
      distanceMultiplier: earthRadius
    }
  },
  {
    $group:{
      _id: "default",
      in_default_radius: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $lt: ["$distance", <default_radius>] }, then: 1, else: 0 } } },
      in_extended_radius: { $sum: 1 },
      in_extended_radius_with_a_cond: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$something", "something"] }, then: 1, else: 0 } } }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible for a number of reasons which are all quite reasonable really.

- While I see what you are trying to achieve, the basic premise is that [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is an identifier for a pipeline stage in itself and therefore can only be used that way.
- The second case here is that what you seem to be looking for is some sort of "operator" that would actually return a [**`$geoWithin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) type of result in a logical (true/false) way to be used in a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. Where this falls over as a concept is that "geo-spatial" queries require an index to be used, and for that reason the only place in the aggregation pipeline that can make use of an index is the very first stage, which typically "should" be a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage.

As stated, the concept is quite reasonable as at no other time than that initial pipeline stage are you really going to have anything that actually matches the document on which the index was created. The new document "copies" exist only within the pipeline processing and therefore do not have an associated index.

While it is clear your intention is to to "test" data for locations within various sets, your best approach is to use several queries to do so and combine the results in code or otherwise write out to another collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it indeed helped figure out how things work :)